# Android does not seem to support ScrollViews with overflow set to visible

Tags: react-native

I need help with scroll views and overflow and how functionality works differently on both iOS and Android.

https://snack.expo.io/NhEfrwN3w

If you run this on iOS and tap the dropdown, it works fine. But if you do so on Android, there are issues. How can I fix this? It looks like overflow support on Android is a relatively new thing (past year or two), but reading the changelogs it seems like this was an issue in the past that is now resolved despite the fact that I still have the issue.

Comment: There always are issues with the android support of overflow, some of the things are still not fixed by RN team (I myself ran into some issues recently). In your particular example, do you need the dropdown picker inside the scrollview?

Comment: I don’t need it but from a design perspective it’d look good. I am open to altering my design a bit, but I’m really adamant about getting this to work.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work with a little trick, although be careful when using it.

You could give a `paddingBottom` to your `contentContainerStyle` of your ScrollView, and then the same value, but negative, as a `marginBottom`. That way your content inside is going to be displayed, and `ScrollView` in itself won't be moved.

So your final style would be:

```
optionsBar: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingBottom: 150, // whatever the height you have here
    marginBottom: -150,
  },
```

Do consider that it is a hack, but Android always has problems with overflow, and more so inside the ScrollView.

Comment: It seems to display fine, but touch inputs unfortunately do not work. This is obviously crucial in my case because I am using a dropdown menu component, so I'm wondering if there is any way to go about this.

Comment: Thanks, worked for me since it doesn't need to be touchable!